How to realize three.js sphere rotation effect, click on the list of countries, the sphere goes to the corresponding country?
Implement three.js sphere rotation effects, click on the list of countries, the sphere to the corresponding country, and mark the landmarks in the map, there are clicking, crossing and other characteristics, need to realize the effect of the Figure,website:https://chn.sectsco.org/
enter image description here
enter image description here



        Threejs实现绘制地球，地理位置标注-经纬度转换世界坐标
        
        
        
        
        
        
    
    
         
            
            
                
            
        
        
             body {
                    margin: 0;
                    overflow: hidden;
                }
            #container {
                display: flex;
                height: 100vh;
            }

            #left {
                flex: 1;
                overflow-y: auto;
                padding: 20px;
            }

            #right {
                flex: 2;
                position: relative;
            }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var camera;
        var renderer;
        var radius = 100; // 地球半径
        var areas = [{
            name: "中国",
            position: [104.19, 35.86]
        }, {
            name: "印度共和国",
            position: [78.96, 20.59]
        }, {
            name: "哈萨克斯坦共和国",
            position: [48.01, 66.92]
        }, {
            name: "吉尔吉斯共和国",
            position: [74.76, 41.20]
        }, {
            name: "巴基斯坦伊斯兰共和国",
            position: [69.34, 30.37]
        }, {
            name: "俄罗斯联邦",
            position: [105.31, 61.52]
        }, {
            name: "塔吉克斯坦共和国",
            position: [71.27, 38.86]
        }, {
            name: "科威特",
            position: [47.97, 29.37]
        }, {
            name: "阿拉伯联合酋长国",
            position: [53.84,  23.42]
        }, {
            name: "缅甸联邦共和国",
            position: [95.95,  21.91]
        }, {
            name: "马尔代夫共和国",
            position: [73.22,  3.20]
        }, {
            name: "巴林王国",
            position: [50.63,  25.93]
        }, {
            name: "卡塔尔国",
            position: [51.18, 25.35]
        }, {
            name: "沙特阿拉伯王国",
            position: [45.07, 23.88]
        }, {
            name: "阿拉伯埃及共和国",
            position: [30.80, 26.82]
        }, {
            name: "斯里兰卡民主社会主义共和国",
            position: [7.87, 80.77]
        }, {
            name: "土耳其共和国",
            position: [38.96, 35.24]
        }, {
            name: "尼泊尔联邦民主共和国",
            position: [28.39, 84.12]
        }, {
            name: "柬埔寨王国",
            position: [12.56, 104.99]
        }, {
            name: "亚美尼亚共和国",
            position: [40.06, 45.03]
        }, {
            name: "阿塞拜疆共和国",
            position: [40.14, 47.57]
        }, {
            name: "蒙古",
            position: [46.86, 103.84]
        }, {
            name: "阿富汗伊斯兰共和国",
            position: [33.93, 67.71]
        }, {
            name: "白俄罗斯共和国",
            position: [53.70, 27.95]
        }, {
            name: "伊朗伊斯兰共和国",
            position: [32.42, 53.68]
        }, {
            name: "乌兹别克斯坦共和国",
            position: [41.37,  64.58]
        }];

        function init() {
            // 创建一个场景，它将包含我们所有的元素，如物体，相机和灯光。
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var cubeLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
            var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

            // 创建一个摄像机，它定义了我们正在看的地方
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 675 / 675, 10, 10000);
            // 摄像机位置
            camera.position.z = 300;
            
            scene.lookAt(scene.position);
            var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
            // to disable zoom
            //orbit.enableZoom = false;
            orbit.enableRotate =true; //启用旋转
            orbit.enablePan = true; //启用平移
            // 注册一个回调函数，当鼠标拖动球体时触发
            orbit.addEventListener('change', function () {
                var currentPosition = orbit.target;
                console.log("当前 camera 的位置：", camera.position);
            });

            // 创建一个渲染器并设置大小，WebGLRenderer将会使用电脑显卡来渲染场景
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true,
                logarithmicDepthBuffer: true,
            });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight("#ffffff", 1);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            // 在屏幕上显示坐标轴
            var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper(radius);
            scene.add(axes);
            
            

            createEarth();
            createAreaPoint();
            

            var rs = coordinateWorldTurnScreen(10, 0, 10);
            console.log(rs)

             // 将呈现器的输出添加到HTML元素
            document.getElementById("dom").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            // 创建国家列表
            var countryList = document.getElementById("left");
            areas.forEach(function(area) {
                var listItem = document.createElement("div");
                listItem.textContent = area.name;
                listItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    animateToCountry(area.position);
                });
                countryList.appendChild(listItem);
            });

            // 启动动画
            renderScene();  

            // 世界坐标转屏幕坐标
            function coordinateWorldTurnScreen(x, y, z) {
                let world_vector = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
                let vector = world_vector.project(camera);
                let halfWidth = window.innerWidth / 2,
                    halfHeight = window.innerHeight / 2;
                return {
                    x: Math.round(vector.x * halfWidth + halfWidth),
                    y: Math.round(-vector.y * halfHeight + halfHeight)
                }
            }

            // 创建地球 半径100
            function createEarth() {
                var earthGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, 50, 50);
                var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                textureLoader.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; // 设置跨域属性为 "anonymous"
                var earthMater = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    map: textureLoader.load('https://cdndc.img.ria.ru/dc/kay-n/2023/shos-2023/assets/map.png'),
                    //transparent: true,
                    //depthWrite: false,
                    //side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    //blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
                    //opacity: 0.8,
                    //color: 0xffffff
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    opacity: 1,
                    color: 0xffffff
                });
                var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeo, earthMater);
                earthMesh.name = "earth"
                scene.add(earthMesh)
                
            }
             
             

            function createAreaPoint() {
                // 球面
                let sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 20, 20),
                    sphereMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                        color: 0x03d98e,
                        wireframe: true
                    })
                let sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, sphereMat)
                scene.add(sphere)
                // 地标
                for (let i = 0, length = areas.length; i < length; i++) {
                    const position = createPosition(this.areas[i].position)
                    createHexagon(position); // 地标
                }
            }

            // 添加经纬度线
            var latLinesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xc8dfff});
            var lonLinesMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xc8dfff});

            // 经度线
            for (var i = -90; i <= 90; i += 10) {
                var latLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                for (var j = -90; j <= 90; j += 1) {
                    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                    vertex.x = Math.sin(j * Math.PI / 90) * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 90) * radius;
                    vertex.y = Math.cos(j * Math.PI / 90) * radius;
                    vertex.z = Math.sin(j * Math.PI / 90) * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 90) * radius;
                    latLineGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
                }
                var latLine = new THREE.Line(latLineGeometry, latLinesMaterial);
                scene.add(latLine);
            }

            // 纬度线
            for (var i = -90; i <= 90; i += 10) {
                var lonLineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                for (var j = -90; j <= 90; j += 1) {
                    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                    vertex.x = Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 90) * Math.cos(j * Math.PI / 90) * radius;
                    vertex.y = Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 90) * radius;
                    vertex.z = Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 90) * Math.sin(j * Math.PI / 90) * radius;
                    lonLineGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
                }
                var lonLine = new THREE.Line(lonLineGeometry, lonLinesMaterial);
                scene.add(lonLine);
            }

             // 创建地标标记
            function createHexagon(position) {
                var hexagon = new THREE.Object3D()
                let hexagonLine = new THREE.CircleGeometry(4, 6)
                let hexagonPlane = new THREE.CircleGeometry(3, 6)
                let vertices = hexagonLine.vertices
                vertices.shift() // 第一个节点是中心点
                let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: 0xffff00,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    opacity: 0.5
                })
                let circleLine = new THREE.LineLoop(hexagonLine, material)
                let circlePlane = new THREE.Mesh(hexagonPlane, material)
                circleLine.position.copy(position)
                circlePlane.position.copy(position)
                circlePlane.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))
                circleLine.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0))

                hexagon.add(circleLine)
                hexagon.add(circlePlane)
                scene.add(hexagon);
            }


            

            function renderScene() {
                orbit.update();
                TWEEN.update(); // 更新 tween.js 动画状态
                // 使用requestAnimationFrame函数进行渲染
                requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
                
            }
            function animateToCountry(position) {
                var targetPosition = createPosition(position); // 将经纬度转换为三维坐标
                var targetHeight = 300; // 相机的目标高度
                var duration = 1000; // 动画持续时间，单位毫秒

                // 创建 tween.js 动画对象
                var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({ x: camera.position.x, y: camera.position.y, z: camera.position.z })
                    .to({ x: targetPosition.x, y: targetPosition.y, z: targetPosition.z }, duration)
                    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.InOut) // 使用 Quadratic InOut 缓动函数实现平滑效果
                    .onUpdate(function(position) {
                        // 保持相机高度
                        position.y = targetHeight;
                        camera.position.set(position.x, position.y, position.z);
                        camera.lookAt(scene.position); // 保持相机朝向场景中心
                    })
                    .onComplete(function () {
                        console.log('tween--finish');
                    })
                    .start(); // 启动动画
            }


            
            // 渲染的场景
            renderer.setSize(675, 675);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        window.onload = init;
        
        

            // 坐标转换，
            function createPosition(lnglat) {
                let spherical = new THREE.Spherical
                spherical.radius = radius;
                const lng = lnglat[0]
                const lat = lnglat[1]
                const theta = (lng + 90) * (Math.PI / 180)
                const phi = (90 - lat) * (Math.PI / 180)
                spherical.phi = phi; // phi是方位面（水平面）内的角度，范围0~360度
                spherical.theta = theta; // theta是俯仰面（竖直面）内的角度，范围0~90度
                let position = new THREE.Vector3()
                position.setFromSpherical(spherical)
                return position
            }

        // 随着窗体的变化修改场景
        function onResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            //renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }
        
        // 监听窗体调整大小事件
        //window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
    </script>

